# inserting systimestamp that is precision 9

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to get a oracle timestamp(9) populated with the full 9 precision at instert with systimestamp

```
column MY_TS format 99999999999999999999999999

SElECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSSSSFF'), '99999999999999999999999999') as MY_TS FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE T1 (MY_TS timestamp(9));
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(systimestamp);
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(MY_TS, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSSSSFF'), '99999999999999999999999999') as MY_TS FROM T1;
```

Yeilds

```
                      MY_TS
---------------------------
    20180802152155270705139


Table created.


1 row created.


                      MY_TS
---------------------------
 20180802152155270735103000
```

Which seems to be loosing the last 3 digit precision.

I keep reading that the Oracle default for systimestamp is 6, but can be modified.  Yet I can't seem to run into a page that says how that is done (most are concerned with formation from the value).

Comment: Where have you seen documentation that states systimestamp return 9 digits for fraction of seconds?

Comment: [TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50950) Accepted values of *fractional_seconds_precision* are 0 to 9. The default is 6.

Comment: What operating system is the server running? The precision of the system time relies on the precision supplied by the operating system so if you are running an operating system that does not support accuracy down to nano-second precision then whatever settings you change in Oracle to increase the precision cannot have any effect.

Comment: Why are you using `HH24MI` and using `SSSSS` which is seconds since midnight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which seems to be loosing the last 3 digit precision.

It is not losing the last 3 digits precision; the `FF` format model is showing the [default precision of the data type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref419):

> ```
> FF [1..9]
> ```
>
> Fractional seconds; no radix character is printed (use the X format element to add the radix character). Use the numbers 1 to 9 after FF to specify the number of digits in the fractional second portion of the datetime value returned. **If you do not specify a digit, then Oracle Database uses the precision specified for the datetime datatype or the datatype's default precision.**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF') as MY_TS FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFFFFFFFF' FROM DUAL;
```

Output:

```
MY_TS                 
-----------------------
20180802230042489334   
YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFFFFFFFF
```

So, it is only outputting fractional seconds to microsecond precision which is [the default precision](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50950):

> ```
> TIMESTAMP [(fractional_seconds_precision)]
> ```
>
> Year, month, and day values of date, as well as hour, minute, and second values of time, where *`fractional_seconds_precision`* is the number of digits in the fractional part of the SECOND datetime field. Accepted values of *`fractional_seconds_precision`* are 0 to 9. **The default is 6**. The default format is determined explicitly by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter or implicitly by the `NLS_TERRITORY` parameter. The sizes varies from 7 to 11 bytes, depending on the precision. This datatype contains the datetime fields `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, `HOUR`, `MINUTE`, and `SECOND`. It contains fractional seconds but does not have a time zone.

If you change the precision of the timestamp:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(systimestamp(9), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF') as MY_TS FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFFFFFFFF' FROM DUAL;
```

Output:

```
MY_TS                 
-----------------------
20180802230708135745000
YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFFFFFFFF
```

Which gives a `TIMESTAMP` with 9 digits precision.

You could also specify the precision in the output format using the `FF9` format model (rather than just `FF` which uses the data type's default precision):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF9') as MY_TS FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFFFFFFFF' FROM DUAL;
```

Output:

```
MY_TS                 
-----------------------
20180802230936652602000
YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.

In your examples (and when I test on my system) the 7,8,9 precision digits are all 0.  I was expecting these to vary in number which doesn't seem to be the case and would seem to make the extra precision meaningless.  
Is this  as another responder asked, an OS limitation?  This Oracle instance is sitting on a Solaris 11 OS.

Comment: @DrewDowling I cannot get `SYSTIMESTAMP` to give better than micro-second precision in my tests on Solaris, Ubuntu and Windows. It will store nano-second precision using `SYSTIMESTAMP + NUMTODSINTERVAL( 123e-9, 'SECOND' )` to populate the nano-second component. However, do you really need nano-second accuracy from the system timer (and is the processor fast enough to achieve it)? I have tried to time to nano-second accuracy before and each CPU cycle was of the magnitude of 100ns so without a fast CPU it may not even be possible for the CPU to achieve it let alone the operating system.

Comment: That is a good question.  I can say I am working with someone who believes we do, and in fact insists that we were already doing this as a solution to issues in the past.  But to answer your question, no, I have not timed this.  At least now I am armed with a proper understanding.  Thanks again!